# How can i give module name?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, overrides

I need my module folder structure like `app/code/local/ABC/MyNameSpace/MyModule`

## edit

I am working on a project and client insist of overriding any module in local/ABC folder. If I want to override PQR_XYZ module, then it must be added as local/ABC/PQR_XYZ.
There are many other modules overridden with this method but they only overrides models or blocks, and they all work fine.

Please find below code references.
config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <ABC_Amasty_Shopby>
            <version>2.8.2.1</version>
        </ABC_Amasty_Shopby>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <amshopby>
                <rewrite>
                    <top>ABC_Amasty_Shopby_Block_Top</top>
                </rewrite> 
            </amshopby>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

My Block File is in:

```
app/code/local/ABC/Amasty/Shopby/Block/Top.php
```

This is working.

Now for overriding a controller,
config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <ABC_Amazon_Payments>
            <version>1.3.0.1</version>
        </ABC_Amazon_Payments>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <amazon>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>ABC_Amazon_Payments</module>
                    <frontName>abcamazon</frontName>
                </args>
            </amazon>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <rewrite>        
            <ABC_amazon_payments_onepagecontroller>
                <from><![CDATA[#^/amazon_payments/onepage/#]]></from> <!-- Amazon_Payments_OnepageController  -->
                <to>/abcamazon/amazon_payments_onepage/</to> <!-- ABC_Amazon_Payments_OnepageController  -->
            </ABC_amazon_payments_onepagecontroller>
        </rewrite>
    </global>
</config>
```

My controller file:

```
app/code/local/ABC/Amazon/Payments/controllers/OnepageController.php
```

This is not working.
I need to override a controller and for a controller, this structure is not working.

Is it possible?

Comment: no you can't .it must be {codePool}/{NameSpace}/{Module}

Comment: i am sure this is possible but don't know how.

Comment: I am VERY curious for what reason you want to do this. I think you have a problem and you think that this will be the solution... while probably there is a better solution to your initial problem. But then you so have to explain us your initial problem...

Comment: Hi @7ochem, I updated the question, please check.

Comment: @John what is the error that you're getting in case of controller rewrite ? please provide the exception or system logs

Comment: There is no error or exception, it just does not override the controller and fetches the action from original controller.

Comment: @John could you show us the controller file and config.xml file that you have used to overwrite the controller. Need to check the code

Comment: @rajeev, added code for working and not working module overrides.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by editing the file `app/Mage.php`. In this file, Magento sets the include paths here. But by doing this, you update the core and after each update, you'll have to change this back again.

But Magento also loads the `get_include_path()` from your system. So you might also want to add the folder there, but in that case, it will be added at the end of the include path. This means that if file `MyNameSpace/MyModule/Block/Test.php` also exists in `app/code/community`, `app/code/local` or `lib`, that file will be used in stead of your custom path.

But as 7ochem already said, why do you want to use this custom path? Even after editing your original question, I don't see a reason on why to do this.

Comment: You said that right. But from the feedback from OP, he is looking for a permanent solution and in that case eidting core file is highly discouraged.

Comment: Editing the core is ALWAYS discouraged, so adding the path to the vhost's include path might be a better solution. But like I said, if the file exists in the `app/code/community` folder, Magento will load that file.